# Create word document using word(docx) byte array in node js

Tags: node.js, arrays, docx

I am trying to get JSON byte array info of documents such as microsoft word, text file,rich text, pdf etc.to create the corresponding word document etc. in a local folder. I managed to deserialize and get the byte array of a word document. [ 80,75,3,4,20,0,6 ] is the byte array for instance. I am using the below code to accomplish the task. The resulting document I get has weird symbols and seems to be corrupted. I am not able to open the word document. When I store the byte array text in a text file, I can open the file and I get the above mentioned weird symbols. Any input and help to resolve the issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
Readable.push(new Buffer([ 80,75,3,4,20,0,6 ]).toString('utf8'));
Readable.push(null); 
Readable.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('.../Test.docx'));
```

Comment: The word doc is not UTF-8

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. Looking into it from that angle.